# what conditions must a series possess to be telescopic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are series of the type $\sum _{r=1}^∞\frac{1}{\left(Tr\right)\left(T\left(r+1\right)\right)}$ (where Tr denotes rth term)always telescopic?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a telescopic series, you must have an expression of the form
$$\sum V(r+1) - V(r)$$ or a similar equivalent. **The series must involve the difference of two adjacent terms**.

Coming to your question, $\sum \frac{1}{T(r) \cdot T(r+1)}$ is only telescopic when it can be expressed as $\frac 1k\sum \frac{1}{T(r)} -\frac{1}{T(r+1)}$ or $\frac 1k \sum \frac{1}{T(r+1)} -\frac{1}{T(r)}$. **This means that $|T(r+1)-T(r)| = k$ (some constant) for your series to be telescopic.**

Comment: thanks @AniruddhaDeb

Comment: No problem. You can mark it as accepted if you think it answers your question.